# Using put() in Restangular

Tags: angularjs, restangular

This is my coding

```
angular.module('app', ['restangular'])
    .config(function(RestangularProvider) {
        RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://www.abc.local');
    })
    .controller('UpdateController', function($scope, Restangular) {
        $scope.getEmployee = function() {
            var Employee = Restangular.one('employee', 10002);
            Employee.get().then(function(employee) {
                $scope.employee = employee;

                var editEmployee = employee;
                editEmployee.first_name = 'XXX';
                editEmployee.put();
            })
        }
    });
```

Using `Employee.get()`, Restangular made me a `GET http://www.abc.local/employee/1002`, everything worked fine here

But using `editEmployee.put()`, Restangular made me `PUT http://www.abc.local/employee` instead of `PUT http://www.abc.local/employee/10002`, what went wrong here?, please help

Thanks

[image]
<sub>(source: [cubeupload.com](https://i.cubeupload.com/VA41Bi.png))</sub>

Comment: put means your are suppose to provide a data that will sent to resource & will get added into the db

Comment: I read the documentation, it said nothing about how to provide the *route* parameters, how can I make a *PUT* request with `employee/10002` using `.put()`?, please hint

Comment: The data you get from the GET, it probably doesn't have `id` field (with value 1002).

Answer (score 0):

The application I work on only uses "customPUT" like that:

```
 Restangular.all('groups').customPUT($scope.group).then(function() 
                {
                    $scope.serverCallDone();
                }, function()
                {
                    $scope.serverCallError();
                });
```

And server side:

```
@Provider
@Path("groups")
public class GroupsRESTFacade {

    @PUT
    @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    @Transactional    
    public void edit(GroupDetail _group, @Context HttpServletRequest req) {
        // . . .
    }   
}
```

We do not need a REST parameter to specify ID, since ID is contained in sent object.